# Getting the cost of an enum through a JList

Tags: java

so I have 4 JLists to contain 4 different parts of a skateboard, the trucks, the wheels, miscellaneous, and decks.

I have four enums set up in my class SkateBoardParts, as such:

```
public class SkateBoardParts {
    public enum Decks {
        FIRST_DECK(10),
      .... 
    }
    double cost;
    private Decks(double c){
      cost = c;
    }
     ... getCost blah
}
```

In my GUI, I have a button to calculate. I have an action listener on that button. My goal is to get the cost of all the selected values in the JLists and add them together to get a total. I have the JLists set up as fields. How do I do this? Would I get the index and then use that index to select the value in the enum? Something like this? (I get an error on truckIndex)

```
   double total = 0;
   int truckIndex = trucksList.getSelectedIndex();
   total += SkateBoardParts.Trucks.truckIndex.getCost();
```

if you want my entire code for my GUI thus far: 
https://pastebin.com/CiSsV8qR

my enum:
https://pastebin.com/WqXs05aK

Comment: I need more details or a full view of your enum class. I have trouble understanding what you mean with skateboard.trucks

Comment: @NesanMano the original post has been updated to include a pastebin to the enum class.

Answer (score 0):

Define your JList as follows

```
private final JList<SkateBoardParts> trucksList = new JList(trucksArray);
```

In your action listener do the following

```
JList<SkateBoardParts> list = (JList<SkateBoardParts>) e.getSource();
SkateBoardParts obj = (SkateBoardParts) list.getSelectedValue();
obj.getCost();
```

**Update**

Here is an example of [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). Please try to post something similar for better help sooner.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JListExample extends JFrame {
    private final JList<Trucks> trucksList;

    public JListExample() {
        //create the model and add elements
        DefaultListModel<Trucks> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

        for (Trucks truk: Trucks.values()) {
            listModel.addElement(truk);
        }

        //create the list
        trucksList = new JList<>(listModel);

        trucksList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                JList<Trucks> list = (JList<Trucks>) me.getSource();
                Trucks truck = (Trucks) list.getSelectedValue();
                System.out.println("Cost " + truck.getCost());
            }
        });

        add(trucksList);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("JList Example");       
        this.setSize(200, 200);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JListExample();
            }
        });
    }       
}

enum Trucks {
    SEVEN_INCH_AXLE(35),
    EIGHT_INCH_AXLE(40),
    EIGHT_AND_HALF_INCH_AXLE(45);

    double cost;
    private Trucks(double c) {
        cost = c;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow this for adding listener: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609200/adding-an-actionlistener-to-a-jlist

Comment: Hmm.. I'm getting an error. I'll read what you posted right quick.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually figured it out. I moved the arrays of my objects to fields so i could access the array using the selectedindex.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to store the value of each component at the point at which the user selects the part:

```
private double partCost = 0.0;

...

JList<SkateBoardPart> list = new JList(SkateBoardPart.values());
list.addListSelectionListener(ev -> partCost = list.getSelectedValue().getCost());
```

That will keep the cost up to date each time the user selects a part.